# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed, with java >1.6

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, jvm

I have a Java JAR application which connects to the Java web service running on a server behind HTTPS. If I run the JAR with Oracle Java 1.6, then the SSL handshake is successful. However, If I run it with Oracle Java 1.7 or newer, I always get the exception: `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I have imported the certificates to the `cacert` file, and have used VM variable `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` to set the path to the file.

I have found out that there are differences in jsse.jar in different Java version.

Also, this application works like expected on a Unix machine which has IBM version of Java installed: `IBM J9 VM (build 2.7, JRE 1.7.0`

And, it works correctly with IBM JRE on Widnows:

```
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0)
```

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this! Java has `java.security` file in `jre/lib/security` folder, and that file has a property `keystore.type`. This property was set to `Windows-ROOT`, but I have imported certificates in `cacerts` file, and the property should be set to `jks` so that Java reads the cacerts file!