# How to fix InvalidAlgorithmParameterException connecting Spring Boot metrics and Cloudwatch

Tags: spring-boot, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

In Spring Boot I have set up Micrometer to pass metrics to Cloudwatch, however I am receiving a InvalidAlgorithmParameterException / the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty error.

I'm running Spring Boot 2.0.9, Spring Framework Cloud 2.0.1 and Micrometer 1.0.10.  This application is deployed in a Docker container through ECS.  What do I need to do to trust the certificate?

AWS specific properties for application.properties:

```
management.metrics.export.cloudwatch.namespace=test
management.metrics.export.cloudwatch.batchSize=20
cloud.aws.region.auto=true
cloud.aws.region.static=
```

When I run my application I am getting the following error:

```
22:58:38
2019-04-08 22:58:38.877 ERROR 25 --- [pool-1-thread-4] i.m.cloudwatch.CloudWatchMeterRegistry : Error sending metric data.
2019-04-08 22:58:38.877 ERROR 25 --- [pool-1-thread-4] i.m.cloudwatch.CloudWatchMeterRegistry : Error sending metric data.
22:58:38 com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.doInvoke(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:1340) ~[aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.invoke(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:1316) ~[aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClient.executePutMetricData(AmazonCloudWatchClient.java:1223) ~[aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38
at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient$14.call(AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.java:774) [aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient$14.call(AmazonCloudWatchAsyncClient.java:768) [aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1903) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1402) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy113.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1236) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.280.jar:na]
22:58:38 ... 15 common frames omitted
22:58:38 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
22:58:38 at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:181) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:312) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
22:58:38 ... 36 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this question is to ensure Java trusts the certificates in question via the cacerts file.

[See the correct way to import root and intermediate certs into java cacerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027922/correct-way-to-import-root-and-intermediate-certifiacts-in-java-cacerts)

The longer answer to my particular question is that I had an invalid cacerts file, so Java was trusting nothing.
I had copied AWS Corretto JVM into the tomcat docker image and the cacerts file was an invalid symbolic link.

Replacing the cacerts file in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/jre/lib with the OS version (/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts) solved the problem.  The OS cacerts file already includes the AWS certificates.