# AWS SDK throws java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException when using Java 8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk

I am getting:

```
 "Unable to execute HTTP request: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"
```

When using AWS SDK On Java 1.8, or to be more exact When I execute:

```
AWSSecretsManager.getSecretValue
```

Thing is, everything works fine when I shift to Java 15.(I must stick to Java 8) I tried the suggestions from the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027922/correct-way-to-import-root-and-intermediate-certificates-in-java-cacerts) with no success. Any help or lead would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty ?

Comment: Yes! one of the last suggestions on that topic was to overwrite the cacert from Java 15 on Java 8 and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Secret Manager V1 or V2 Java API.

I just tested the Secret Manager V2 code example here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager/src/main/java/com/example/secrets/GetSecretValue.java

and it works perfectly with Java 1.8.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I eventually found the solution by overwriting cacert from Java 15 on Java 8. I did try to go your suggested route, however Maven cant find <dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.76</version>
</dependency>
I tried different repositories and nothing.

Comment: Very strange as I have no issue with Java 1.8 and the POMs here: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager

Comment: if you use aws/secretmanager as an Encryption key, you do not need to use TrustStore I think.